# How to access unzipped files in azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Scenario is like this:
I have 2 pipelines.
First pipeline builds nuGet package as a tool and publishes to artifact feed.
That tool have appsettings.json file in witch I want to access some folder relative to that path. For example `./TestFolder`

Second pipeline extracts zip to that `TestFolder`, installs tool globally with `dotnet tool install -g` and run the tool.

My question is, how can I extract that zip to folder where tool is located?
How this scenario is done in general?
I hope you understand me

Comment: Hi, have you checked my instructions to test if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your situation, you can use this task "Extract files" [Extract Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=azure-devops) to extract that zip and then specify the
destinationFolder as "TestFolder" where tool is located.

```
steps:
- task: ExtractFiles@1
  displayName: 'Extract files '
  inputs:
    destinationFolder: TestFolder
```